# How do I update a Logical File definition after adding a column using SQL

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I added a new column to a table (physical file) in DB2/400 v6r1 using an SQL ALTER TABLE statement. I have a logical file based on that table and the new field doesn't appear in it. Is there a way update that logical file without deleting and recreating it?

Comment: No way that I'm aware of - and of course if you recompile the Logical File it will have a new File Level Identifier so if your programs are checking that (and they probably are) they will get a level check the next time they run unless you recompile them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

You will need to recompile the logical.

If the field was added at the end of the record, you *might* be able to get away with turning level checking off on it, `LVLCHK(*NO)`.  This might allow you get away with not recompiling some programs, IF they use it only for input and do not need the new field.  This option leaves many practitioners rather nervous, others think it's great.  Use with care.  Programs that access the file only via SQL may be exempt.  All other programs that use the logical or physical with native I/O must be recompiled.

One side benefit of using only SQL in your programs -- fewer recompiles required.

**Edit**

To be clear -

You need to recompile all logicals that refer to the changed physical.

You need to recompile any programs that use native I/O to write or update records in the physical or any of the logicals.

Many (possibly most) will tell you to also recompile programs that only read the the file (PF or LF).

Some will tell you that IF you only add new fields to the end of the record format, then you *might* not need to recompile programs that use native I/O only to read the file.  If you do this, you will want to either a) using OVRDBF LVLCHK(*NO) only when about to call these programs, and DLTOVR afterwards, or b) create or change the file(s) to have LVLCHK(*NO).

Both have risks.  WARNING:  *These stunts have been performed by professionals.  Do not try at home.*

In other words, if your shop is not experienced enough to understand & properly deal with the issues carefully & completely, then play its safe.  Definitely.  If you've had to ask this question, you're not nearly there yet.

If you have added new fields at the beginning or middle of the record layout, or if you have changed the size or type of any existing fields, Do Not Pass GO! You will need recompile all programs that use the file(s).

Comment: If you added a TIMESTAMP to the end of the table in SQL with a default value and had it update via trigger AND you didn't care if any of the LFs were aware of it, would that be safe/require any compilations?  Our 400 developer pointed to pages of LFs that would have to get updated as a reason to not do it but I just want my SSIS package to know which rows were changed in the last N minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Recompile the LF (assuming it was created with DDS) or do an ALTER VIEW to update it in SQL.

Comment: This involves deleting and recreating the logical.  The question was can it be accomplished without doing that.

Comment: I don't think so ... you'll also have to recompile any native programs that use the LF, as the record format level identifier will change.

Comment: You don't think recompiling constitutes (deleting and) recreating it? Why do you say that?

Comment: As far as needing to recompile programs, see my answer.

Comment: LVLCHK(*NO) is an accident waiting to happen ... the long term risks **FAR** out weigh any short term benefits.  FWIW: A good change control system will help manage the file change and any necessary related object recompiles (note: I work for a change control vendor).

Comment: So you fall into the group that is nervous about this practice.  There are others who feel differently. It is controversial. I don't think I endorsed either side, or didn't mean to.  In my travels as a consultant I have seen both sides. I have seen a *very* risk averse Fortune 500 company *require* LVLCHK(*NO). For them, they saw more costs and risks with recompiling 100s or 1000s of programs.  By being rigorously careful, they did not encounter problems. One size does not fit all & YMMV.

Comment: That Fortune 500 company clearly doesn't understand the platform they are working with ... defeating a very basic, built in, system protection is just plain dumb.  If an organization has that many programs that need to be recompiled (with little to no risk, as long as the application isn't changed) they clearly should be using some form of change control.

Comment: Actually, no. I too was highly concerned at first, just as you are. I have seen it done elsewhere as an simple expediency.  But this place was highly rigorous and did know exactly what they were doing.  They had in the neighborhood of 100 people in software engineering for iSeries development, with a team of DB2 for i DBA's.  They had the most thorough set of design, development, and test practices I have seen anywhere.  It was a highly risk averse environment, and this practice was very carefully thought out and coordinated.